# How to use AWS SES with tomcat application in Docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, smtp, amazon-ses

I have a tomcat application running in a docker container, which itself is located on an aws ec2 ubuntu server behind an application load balancer. I now want to use aws ses to enable the application to send out emails on certain actions. I have, however, no clue how to do this.
The ec2 instance role allows for the sending of email through ses, I have  an SES verified identity linked to the domain and have obtained SMTP credentials, but more than that, I don't know. Where in the app should I put the port nr, user/password and host name in order to use SES for the app to send emails?

As this pertains to a legacy application with absolutely no documentation (classic) I have been searching the source code, .properties files, web.xml, you name it, for any mention of an smtp or mail client but I have found none.

Answer (score 0):

You can install aws cli on docker image you are using and insert authorized IAM credentials (access key / secret key) to send e-mail via SES, create a bash script using aws cli with the help of this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ses/send-email.html , after on your application you can trigger this previous created script with some kind of html template to send you app e-mail.